# The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

```
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `App.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.

Integrating target `Pods-App` (`../../../../var/folders/96/pt3x8nrn0js43x0tjv5mjf7w0000gv/T/CocoaPods/Lint/App.xcodeproj` project)
  Adding Build Phase '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' to project.
  Adding Build Phase '[CP] Copy Pods Resources' to project.
  Adding Build Phase '[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock' to project.
  - Running post install hooks
  Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.
   Building with xcodebuild. 
xcodebuild clean build -workspace App.xcworkspace -scheme App -configuration Release CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=- -sdk iphonesimulator -destination id=1339F4AE-70BA-42D5-A7D1-45DA93A78C9E
Build settings from command line:
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = -
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator10.0

=== CLEAN TARGET BSTableViewReorder OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
“Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.
“Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

** CLEAN FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
=== BUILD TARGET BSTableViewReorder OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
“Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.
“Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
 -> BSTableViewReorder (1.5)
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb:77:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/bin/pod:55:in `'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `'
```

Do you know what happens here? I updated project to current Swift Syntax. I use Xcode 8 and Swift 3.0.

[image]

When I change it to YES, then:

[image]

When I try to `pod update` then:

```
kuna@Cleverland:~/GIthub/BSTableViewReorder/Example$ pod install
[!] The specification of arguments as a string has been deprecated Pod::Command::Try: `NAME`

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] Unsupported options `{:exclusive=>true}` for target `BSTableViewReorder_Example`..

 #  from /Users/kuna/Github/BSTableViewReorder/Example/Podfile:4
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >  target 'BSTableViewReorder_Example', :exclusive => true do
 #    pod "BSTableViewReorder", :path => "../"
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

This is my *Podfile*:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

target 'BSTableViewReorder_Example', :exclusive => true do
  pod "BSTableViewReorder", :path => "../"
end

target 'BSTableViewReorder_Tests', :exclusive => true do
  pod "BSTableViewReorder", :path => "../"
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Try alt+command+shift+k and then re-compile.

Comment: I did it and it is not going to work still:( I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your pod file try to include these lines:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
    end
  end
end
```

and leave "Legacy Swift..." set to YES

Comment: Still the same problem: `Module compiled with Swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 2.3`

Comment: have you run pod integrate and pod install ?

Comment: I did and I have an error. The error I just added to the question.